# Xamarin Form Tabbed page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Hi I try to develop my first cross app with Xamarin, I try to do a tabbed page. 
my xaml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:MyTimesheet.Pages"

             x:Class="MyTimesheet.MainRootPage">
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

    <local:Page1></local:Page1>
    <local:Page2></local:Page2>
</TabbedPage>
```

My page1 and page 2  the xaml code are the same:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyTimesheet.Pages.ClientiPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome Clienti" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I found more example that use my approch but when i build a solution my error are:

the type 'TabbedPage' could not found.
the type 'local:page1' could not found.

what is wrong?
thankyou regards

the screenshot required:
[image]

New error - new screenshot:

Comment: Can print screen the exact error statement and upload it here?

Comment: i have visual studio not in english so I traslate the error

Comment: Try check the xmlns:local. It should be in this format: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Pages;assembly=MyTimesheet"

Comment: Also, when TabbedPage reference is not found, it might means something wrong with your reference to Xamarin.Forms packages. Try to check whether the packages is installed correctly. Or try to remove the package then reinstall back.

Comment: new screen shot attached the local format generate a lot error... :-(

Comment: As @ganchito55 mentions below: `using` inside a `xmlns` declaration is invalid. That only works in UWP. Xamarin uses the old syntax as found in WPF and friends

Answer (score 0):

I use ReSharper and it shows me two problems:

1. This code is wrong `xmlns:local="using:MyTimesheet.Pages"`, you have to changed it to `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Pages,assembly=MyTimesheet"`
2. Check the TabbedPage code behind (TabbedPage.xaml.cs) and for me Visual Studio creates the following wrong code `public partial class TabbedPage : TabbedPage`, remove the inherit (use `public partial class TabbedPage`) and for me, it works.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `xmlns:local="using:MyTimesheet.Pages` and replace `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Views`

Then replace your `<local:Page1></local:Page1>` with `<view:Page1/>`. That works in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<Page1   Title="Page 1" /> 
<Page2   Title="Page 2" />
```

Xamarin will Automatically Add your References

also you can set title inside pages

```
 <ContentPage  Title="page 4">
```